# Properly return a unique ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a String class `MyString` (yes, as homework) and have to offer a `toCString` method which returns a `unique_ptr<char[]>` (and not a `Vector`). Unfortunately I fail when returning the pointer to the caller: The result is always filled with wrong content - it seems that I create the pointer and/or the character array on the stack.

```
unique_ptr<char[]> MyString::toCString() const {
     char *characters = new char[m_len];
     char *thisString = m_string.get();
     for (int i = 0; i < m_len; i++) {
         characters[i] = *(thisString + m_start + i);
     }
     const unique_ptr<char[], default_delete<char[]>> &cString = unique_ptr<new char[m_len]>(characters);
     return cString;
}
```

When debugging I always get expected behaviour. Problems only occur on callers site. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you returning a smart pointer? _C_ string is a mere pointer to `char` (and not to an array)

Comment: `unique_ptr<new char[m_len]>(characters)` This makes no sense, and doesn't compile. Show your actual code.

Comment: You are allocating the smart pointer on the stack as a reference, then exiting the function.  This will produce unpredictable behavior even if that behavior seems to be correct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643563/how-to-return-smart-pointers-shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value

Comment: @NathanielJohnson The function returns by value - just as the article you cite recommends. It does not return a reference or a pointer to a local variable. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Its a reference not a copy.

Comment: @ForceBru because I must not change the method signatures.

Comment: Your new edit completely changed the code.

Comment: @Kenneth You edited the code, which makes your question meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see there is already an accepted answer, but this does not solve the problem. The problem on the client side is occurring because you're not null-terminating the c-string.

I don't know what type m_string is, so lets for a moment assume that it's a std::string. You can translate the actual methods yourself:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> MyString::toCString() const 
{
    // get length (in chars) of string
    auto nof_chars = m_string.size();

    // allocate that many chars +1 for the null terminator.
    auto cString = std::unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[nof_chars + 1]};

    // efficiently copy the data - compiler will replace memcpy
    // with an ultra-fast sequence of instructions in release build
    memcpy(cString.get(), m_string.data(), nof_chars * sizeof(char));

    // don't forget to null terminate!!
    cString[nof_chars] = '\0';

    // now allow RVO to return our unique_ptr
    return cString;
}
```

As per Christophe's suggestion, here's the method again, written in terms of std::copy_n. Note that the std::copy[_xxx] suite of functions all return an iterator that addresses one-past the last write. We can use that to save recomputing the location of the null terminator. Isn't the standard library wonderful?

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> MyString::toCString() const 
{
    // get length (in chars) of string
    auto nof_chars = m_string.size();

    // allocate that many chars +1 for the null terminator.
    auto cString = std::unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[nof_chars + 1]};

    // efficiently copy the data - and don't forget to null terminate
    *std::copy_n(m_string.data(), nof_chars, cString.get()) = '\0';

    // now allow RVO to return our unique_ptr
    return cString;
}
```

Comment: Apparently the object represents a substring of the `m_string`, hence `m_start` and `m_len`.  But you are absolutely correct about making space and adding a NUL terminator.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to replace the use of the [old `memcpy()` with a `std::copy()`  or `std::copy_n()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/is-it-better-to-use-stdmemcpy-or-stdcopy-in-terms-to-performance) ?

Comment: @Christophe agreed, it would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Christophe your suggestion added as a second version of toCString. I think your idea is better.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a reference to a unique_ptr like you did.  Instead, return the unique_ptr directly:  the move constructor will take care of everything:

```
 return unique_ptr<char[], default_delete<char[]>>(characters);
```

Comment: Also be certain that the c++ compiler supports and enables c++11.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson sure ! On the other hand, if OP uses `unique_ptr` and not the deprecated `auto_ptr`  and moreover could already compile some code with it, I can assume that C++11 is given ;-)

Comment: what you meant to say was, "Return Value Optimisation will take care of everything". Returning efficiently by value doesn't even need a move constructor.

Comment: @RichardHodges yes, indeed: the copy/move elision rules for return values may make the situation even better !  However I didn't mention it in my answer, because the move construction is the real enabler, as according to 12.8/31, implementations are allowed to do copy/move elision but aren't obliged to do so.

Comment: @Christophe understood. FYI There's a proposal before the committee to require copy elision in c++17. Here's hoping it passes!

Comment: @RichardHodges Interesting ! I wasn't aware, thanks. It would indeed be good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have edited your question, and now you are using

```
unique_ptr<char[]> cString = unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[m_len]};
```

First improvement: use auto

```
auto cString = unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[m_len]};
```

Second improvement: your tag is C+11, but if you happen to be using C+14, then use `std::make_unique` like this:

```
auto cString = std::make_unique<char[]>(m_len);
```

Further more, as Scott Meyers would say, if you are using C+11, then simply write the `make_unique` function yourself. It's not hard, and it's very very useful.

http://ideone.com/IIWyT0

```
template<class T, class... Types>
inline auto make_unique(Types&&... Args) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<T>::value, std::unique_ptr<T>>::type
{
    return (std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Types>(Args)...)));
}

template<class T>
inline auto make_unique(size_t Size) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value && std::extent<T>::value == 0, std::unique_ptr<T>>::type
{
    return (std::unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[Size]()));
}
```