# Return `std::shared_ptr` by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, return, smart-pointers, return-type

I am reading some codebase but I don't quite understand why the below function would return a `reference` (&) to the `std::shared_ptr`. I read in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643563/how-to-return-smart-pointers-shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value) that we should return `std::shared_ptr` by value, because otherwise we won't properly increment the reference count.

So I am just trying to guess the reason.

- Does it have something to do with the the member function being
  `static`? Or the return value being `static`?
- Does it have something to do with `thread`
  as the name suggests? Could anyone point me to some reading or
  give some direction?

```
class A {
    public:
        A() {...}
        ~A() {...}
        ...
        static std::shared_ptr<A>& ThreadLocal() {
            static std::shared_ptr<A> inst = std::make_shared<A>();
            if (inst == nullptr) {
                inst = std::make_shared<A>();
            }
            return inst;
        }
        static void Shutdown() {
            ThreadLocal().reset();
        }
    private:
        ...
}
```

Comment: `ThreadLocal` using `static` rather than `thread_local`? What the deuce?

Comment: TBH that all looks a little dubious to me.

Comment: `static` in a declaration always apply to the name being declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons it's returned by reference is to reset the static shared pointer. You can see that there is some logic to create a new one for whatever business logic the static pointer could need to be reset.

And no, no logic for threads here.

Comment: Hmm great point! I also question myself why would one want to check that line: `if (inst == nullptr)`.

Comment: I'd like to spend some time a bit more diving into the code to see exactly why. But your answer gives me a really good direction of where to look into.